# Jackson: referencing the same object

Tags: java, json, jackson

There are some cases where the data serialized or unserialized in a body, for example, a JSON body, contains references to the same object. For example, a JSON body with a list of players, and a list of teams composed of these players:

```
{
  "players": [
    { "name": "Player 1" },
    { "name": "Player 2" },
    { "name": "Player 3" },
    { "name": "Player 4" },
    { "name": "Player 5" },
    { "name": "Player 6" },
    { "name": "Player 7" },
    { "name": "Player 8" }
  ],
  "teams": [
    {
      "name": "Team 1",
      "players": [
        { "name": "Player 1"},
        { "name": "Player 2"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Team 2",
      "players": [
        { "name": "Player 3"},
        { "name": "Player 4"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Team 3",
      "players": [
        { "name": "Player 5"},
        { "name": "Player 6"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Team 4",
      "players": [
        { "name": "Player 7"},
        { "name": "Player 8"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can imagine *Player X* refers to the same object, but potentially we could end up with an unwanted scenario where *Player X* is represented by different objects.

I would like to know what is the best and most common approach to these scenarios. I can think of several ways of doing this:

1. Add an ID attribute to the `Player` class. My design does not include an ID becase it is not needed. The ways of identifying an object are by its reference and if they're contained in a collection, by their position in it (if the collection has positions). This might be considered a bad practice, but I did it intentionally and I don't plan on changing it unless necessary.
2. Also having a player ID, but instead of serializing/deserializing the teams as a list of players, it would just be a list of IDs. Information contained in the JSON body would be lost, but we would have more compact data.
3. Sticking to my ID-less design, similarly to the previous point, I could have a list of positions (which in practice would actually be a player ID because they serve as identification means), so the number *0* would refer to the player in the first position in the *players* list.
4. Changing the contract and having players with unique name. With this we could now have an ID without having to add a new attribute to the class. However I think it is a bad idea because not necessarily all players should have different names.

What would be the best approach? What is usually done? Do you have different suggestions?

Comment: I would print adhesive labels with the player names ("Player 1" ... "Player N") and have the player wear them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went for positioning references. Apparently it is not considered a bad approach necessarily.

So the JSON body would be like this:

```
{
  "players": [
    { "name": "Player 1" },
    { "name": "Player 2" },
    { "name": "Player 3" },
    { "name": "Player 4" }
  ],
  "teams": [
    [ 3, 1 ],
    [ 0, 2 ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I reached something that is close to the requirement in the question:
I used Jackson's [Object Identity Feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity) which allows to define that values of a certain property identify the different instances of the POJO:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
        property="name", scope=Player.class)
public class Player
{
    public String name;

    public Player() {}
    public Player(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String toString() {
        // prints name and java object id 
        return name + "-" + super.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is the rest of the POJO used:

```
public class League
{
    public List<Player> players;
    public List<Team> teams;
}

public class Team
{
    public String name;
    public List<Player> players;

    public Team() {}
    public Team(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String toString() {
        return name + "-" + super.toString() + ":" + players.toString();
    }
}
```

test method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try (Reader reader = new FileReader("C:/Temp/xx.json")) {
        League l = objectMapper.readValue(reader, League.class);
        System.out.println("l.players");
        System.out.println(l.players);
        System.out.println("l.teams");
        System.out.println(l.teams);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the output clearly shows that same objects are used in players and teams:

```
l.players
[Player 1-test.JSONTest$Player@641147d0, Player 2-test.JSONTest$Player@6e38921c, Player 3-test.JSONTest$Player@64d7f7e0, Player 4-test.JSONTest$Player@27c6e487, Player 5-test.JSONTest$Player@49070868, Player 6-test.JSONTest$Player@6385cb26, Player 7-test.JSONTest$Player@38364841, Player 8-test.JSONTest$Player@28c4711c]
l.teams
[Team 1-test.JSONTest$Team@59717824:[Player 1-test.JSONTest$Player@641147d0, Player 2-test.JSONTest$Player@6e38921c], Team 2-test.JSONTest$Team@146044d7:[Player 3-test.JSONTest$Player@64d7f7e0, Player 4-test.JSONTest$Player@27c6e487], Team 3-test.JSONTest$Team@1e9e725a:[Player 5-test.JSONTest$Player@49070868, Player 6-test.JSONTest$Player@6385cb26], Team 4-test.JSONTest$Team@15d9bc04:[Player 7-test.JSONTest$Player@38364841, Player 8-test.JSONTest$Player@28c4711c]]
```

so far so good, so why "something that is close to the requirement"? 
I had to slightly change the input json, in order for Jackson to properly identify that players in teams are references to the ones in players list:

```
{
  "players": [
    { "name": "Player 1" },
    { "name": "Player 2" },
    { "name": "Player 3" },
    { "name": "Player 4" },
    { "name": "Player 5" },
    { "name": "Player 6" },
    { "name": "Player 7" },
    { "name": "Player 8" }
  ],
  "teams": [
    {
      "name": "Team 1",
      "players": [ "Player 1", "Player 2"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Team 2",
      "players": [ "Player 3", "Player 4"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Team 3",
      "players": [ "Player 5", "Player 6"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Team 4",
      "players": [ "Player 7", "Player 8"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: But this would require the name to be an unique identifier wouldn't it? That's an inconvenience I mentioned in my fourth point.

Comment: but the name is the only identifier! who else do you expect jackson (or any other parser) to identify a unique player??

Comment: an ID (in the database sense)

Comment: fine. then use it.

Comment: That would go back to deciding if I should take my suggested approach no. 1 or no. 2.

Comment: you said it yourself - identifying an object by its reference (i.e. doing `if a == b`) is considered bad practice in Java and for a good reason. in any case, if you wish to have multiple references to the same json object, there has to be **something** in the json text itself that identifies an object.