# Deserialize json keeping the reference by an specific field or the equal method

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I have the typical rest api with spring mvc and i send something to a post resource, the json is desearialized and so on, my problem comes when i try to keep references to the same object for the ones that are repeated (what i consider repeated, because their ids are the same).

This is my json (let´s call it bookmark)

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "aName",
"employees": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "aPerson"
}],
"contractors": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "aPerson"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "aSecondPerson"
}]  }
```

When I desearialize the json string to the POJOs (with fasterxml.jakson:2.8.0) i get three different Person objects (the one with id 1 repeated twice and the id 2 once) but i need to have only two (the id 1 once referenced twice and the id 2 once)

This is the parent POJO

```
public class Bookmark {

private Long id;
private String name;
private Set<Person> employees;

private Set<Person> contractors;
... getters and setters
```

The Person POJO

```
public class Person {

private Long id;

private String name;

... equals based on the id
... getters and setters
```

Does Jackson any specific annotation for this? Do I have to implement my own deserializator for this?
I have already tried with @JsonIdentityInfo with no success. I have been looking in the jackson documentation but i can´t find anything related with this.

Clarification:
I´m simplifying the json, in the real world i have something similar to this.

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "aName",
"persons": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "aPerson"
}],
"design": 
{
"name": "aDesign",
"persons":
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "aPerson"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "aSecondPerson"
}]  }}
```

Comment: Do you have `persons` and `persons2` elements in `Person` pojo?

Comment: No, in bookmark POJO as you can see. It´s a simple example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson: referencing the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640985/jackson-referencing-the-same-object)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data contains 2 arrays thats why 2 Set objects are created .

You need JSON structure like this -

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "aName",
"persons": [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "aPerson"
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "bPerson"
    },
    {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "cPerson"
    }
           ] 
}
```

to achieve following Parent Bean Class

```
public class Bookmark {

  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private Set<Person> persons;

  ... getters and setters

  }
```

Comment: I´m simplifying the json struct to make it more understandable, it´s not a matter of improve the json, it´s to keep the same memory references when the objects are the same.
Thanks for the answer.